# How can add regular expression in Jmeter

Tags: jmeter

How can add regular expression extractor for digest value for following post method.

```
<form method="post"
action="ModuleQuickMenu.aspx?mid=65&digest=nvBKUwJ18A66j4IJl7ppGA"
id="form1">
```

Comment: <form method="post" action="ModuleQuickMenu.aspx?mid=65&digest=nvBKUwJ18A66j4IJl7ppGA" id="form1">

Answer (score 0):

Remember that you need to escape `?` sign in your regular expression so it would be something like:

```
<form method="post" action="ModuleQuickMenu.aspx\?mid=65&digest=(.+?)" id="form1">
```

Demo:

[image: JMeter Regular Expression]

References:

- [JMeter: Regular Expressions](http://jmeter.apache.org/usermanual/regular_expressions.html), pay attention to [Meta Characters](http://jmeter.apache.org/usermanual/regular_expressions.html#meta_chars) chapter
- [Using RegEx (Regular Expression Extractor) with JMeter](https://guide.blazemeter.com/hc/en-us/articles/207421325-Using-RegEx-Regular-Expression-Extractor-with-JMeter)
- [Perl 5 Regex Cheat sheet](https://perlmaven.com/regex-cheat-sheet)